# Android asynctask with php

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to write a simple user login gui. I have everything working but I initially had the main thread executing the http request for the php script.  I have since moved this code to an `asynctask` so the UI threaded would not be bogged down. I'm now seeing that its taking almost 60 sec to execute the php script from the background thread were as it took less than 2 sec when in the main thread. Is this normal? How do i speed up the `asynctask`?

AsyncTask code:

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class checkLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Verifying login credentials. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting user details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        //    public void run() {

                // Stores User name
                String username = params[0];

                // Stores Password
                String password = params[1];

                String loginStatus = "";

                try {
                    //Call getUserFromDB to execute php script
                    Log.i("log_tag","Executing doInBackground. user:" +username + " password: "+password);
                    loginStatus = getUserFromDB(username, password);
                    Log.i("log_tag",loginStatus);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e ("log_tag",e.toString());
                }
        //    }
        //});
        return loginStatus;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String loginStatus) {
        Log.i("log_tag","Entered onPostExecute");
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try{
            // Validates the User name and Password 
            if (loginStatus.startsWith("Error")) {                                          
                tv_Message.setText(loginStatus);
            } else {
                tv_Message.setText(R.string.dialog_message_pass);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e ("log_tag",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After some experimenting, I found that the asyncTask continues to run in the doInBackground function until I click on the UI.  Shouldn't the asyncTask run to completion once its started independent of of the UI thread?

Comment: UPDATE - so i found that the query works almost instantaneously if i remove the dialog from pre and postExecute.  So somehow the dialog was hanging the asynctask